# If Statement: Compare multiple ints

Tags: java, android, if-statement, int

I'm developing an app that is getting quite large after 1 year. So I'm trying to improve its performance in all aspects.
I'm not a professional, I've been teaching myself programming for the past year, and when I look back some lines I wrote in the past they look so silly, like the one below:

```
    if (screenPos == 0 || screenPos == 20 || screenPos == 22){

//do something
} else {

}
```

Is there a simplest/shorter way to compare a value with several ints?

something like:

```
    if (screenPos != 0, 20, 22){
    //do something
}
```

or maybe add this numbers in a array list and check "if(screenPos exists in the Array)"?

I know is a newbie question, sorry about that. I've been looking around for an answer, but haven't found it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
ArrayList<Integer> test = Arrays.asList(0,20,22);
//...
if(test.contains(screenpos)){
    //...
}
```

EDIT (Thanks [@Gabe Sechan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1631193/gabe-sechan)): It is more efficient to initialize the `List` outside of the if statement, as was pointed out in the comments.

Of course, it's better to use a switch, really, but if you want something short this would be nice, albeit slightly unconventional

Comment: I'm using your implement, because It's the shortest, and I can use many times to do checks for specific screen numbers. Thanks!

Comment: This is actually inefficient code-  it creates a new List object every time its run.  You're better off initializing the list just once and saving it, creating objects is expensive and doing to multiple times should be avoided.  Also, a Set would be better than a list-  a list can't assume its sorted so ill do a full search rather than a binary search (O(n) vs O(log(n)), and may have the same element multiple times (a set can't).

Comment: Also acceptable would just be a standard loop over the array.  But creating a list just to use contains is a HORRIBLE HORRIBLE habit.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
switch(screenPos) {
    case 0:
    case 20:
    case 22:
        //do something in case screenPos was equal to 0 or 20 or 22
        break;
    default:
        // do something otherwise
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your suggestion does the job, but I found a simpler one, which I'm already using and it's more appropriate for my case.

Answer (score 1):

Well you're checking for concrete integers with no apparent pattern so no natural tricks with modulo, multiplication og division will work. All of the other suggestions above are doable (I like Mulligans the best), but I think the most important thing you should do is to refactor out the condition into another method and do the check here.

This is clearly best practice if you take a classical object oriented programming perspective.